# Preloader question, preloader not on top of the page

Tags: javascript, joomla, preloader

I have made a post yesterday (late in the evening), but that one wasn't very clear to you, so I hope this will be better.

I have found a code which I'd like to use as a preloader for my website. It seems to work, but the problem is that the complete website is still visible. The maker of this script claims that the preloader should cover the website and disappear when the page is loaded.

The preloader does disappear, but the website is on top of the preloader, I have to say that it is a Joomla website, can someone explain to me why it isn't the website isn't covered by the preloader. I think it's because there is a lot of code which is loaded before the actual head section begins.

This is the code:

```
<!-- STEP ONE: Paste this code into the HEAD of your HTML document  -->

<HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Original:  Gilbert Davis -->

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin
function loadImages() {
if (document.getElementById) {  // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
document.getElementById('hidepage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else {
if (document.layers) {  // Netscape 4
document.hidepage.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else {  // IE 4
document.all.hidepage.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
   }
}
//  End -->
</script>
</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Insert the onLoad event handler into your BODY tag  -->

<BODY OnLoad="loadImages()">

<!-- STEP THREE: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<div id="hidepage" style="position: absolute; left:5px; top:5px; background-color: #FFFFCC; layer-background-color: #FFFFCC; height: 100%; width: 100%;"> 

<table width=100%><tr><td>Page loading ... Please wait.</td></tr></table></div> 

<!-- put the rest of your page contents here -->
```

This is the complete code of my template index.php in case you need to know something about it.

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted index access' );
define( 'YOURBASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );

require( YOURBASEPATH.DS."rt_styleswitcher.php");
JHTML::_( 'behavior.mootools' );
global $template_real_width, $leftcolumn_width, $rightcolumn_width, $tstyle;
global $js_compatibility, $menu_rows_per_column, $menu_columns, $menu_multicollevel;
global $showcase_block, $showcase2_block, $showcase3_block, $user1_block, $user2_block, $user3_block, $mainbody_block, $side_block, $user4_block, $user5_block, $user6_block, $user7_block, $user8_block, $user9_block, $splitmenu_col, $frontpage_component;

$live_site              = $mainframe->getCfg('live_site');
$template_path          = $this->baseurl . '/templates/' .  $this->template;
$preset_style           = $this->params->get("presetStyle", "style7");
$frontpage_component    = $this->params->get("enableFrontpage", "show");
$enable_ie6warn         = ($this->params->get("enableIe6warn", 0)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$font_family            = $this->params->get("fontFamily", "affinity");
$enable_fontspans       = ($this->params->get("enableFontspans", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$enable_inputstyle      = ($this->params->get("enableInputstyle", 1) == 0)?"false":"true";
$inputs_exclusion       = $this->params->get("inputsExclusion", "'.content_vote','#login-module'");
$template_width         = $this->params->get("templateWidth", "959");
$leftcolumn_width       = $this->params->get("leftcolumnWidth", "210");
$rightcolumn_width      = $this->params->get("rightcolumnWidth", "260");
$leftinset_width        = $this->params->get("leftinsetWidth", "180");
$rightinset_width       = $this->params->get("rightinsetWidth", "180");
$splitmenu_col          = $this->params->get("splitmenuCol", "rightcol");
$menu_name              = $this->params->get("menuName", "mainmenu");
$menu_type              = $this->params->get("menuType", "moomenu");
$menu_rows_per_column   = $this->params->get("menuRowsPerColumn");
$menu_columns           = $this->params->get("menuColumns");
$menu_multicollevel     = $this->params->get("menuMultiColLevel", 1);
$default_font           = $this->params->get("defaultFont", "default");
$show_date              = ($this->params->get("showDate", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$clientside_date        = ($this->params->get("clientSideDate", 1) == 0)?"false":"true";
$show_logo              = ($this->params->get("showLogo", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$show_logo_slogan       = ($this->params->get("showLogoslogan", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$logo_slogan            = $this->params->get("logoSlogan", "Apr 09 Design");
$show_textsizer         = ($this->params->get("showTextsizer", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$show_topbutton         = ($this->params->get("showTopbutton", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$show_copyright         = ($this->params->get("showCopyright", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$show_defaultsettings   = ($this->params->get("showDefaultsettings", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$thirdparty_styling     = ($this->params->get("thirdpartyStyling", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$js_compatibility       = ($this->params->get("jsCompatibility", 0)  == 0)?"false":"true";

// Module Block Styles
$showcase_block         = $this->params->get("showcaseBlock", "light");
$showcase2_block        = $this->params->get("showcase2Block", "light");
$showcase3_block        = $this->params->get("showcase3Block", "light");
$user1_block            = $this->params->get("user1Block", "light");
$user2_block            = $this->params->get("user2Block", "light");
$user3_block            = $this->params->get("user3Block", "light");
$mainbody_block         = $this->params->get("mainbodyBlock", "light");
$side_block             = $this->params->get("sideBlock", "light");
$user4_block            = $this->params->get("user4Block", "light");
$user5_block            = $this->params->get("user5Block", "light");
$user6_block            = $this->params->get("user6Block", "light");
$user7_block            = $this->params->get("user7Block", "light");
$user8_block            = $this->params->get("user8Block", "light");
$user9_block            = $this->params->get("user9Block", "light");

// sortables options
$sortables              = ($this->params->get("sortableElements", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$sortables_ghost        = $this->params->get("sortableGhost", 1);
$sortables_opacity      = $this->params->get("sortableOpacity", 0.5);
$sortables_radius       = $this->params->get("sortableRadius", 16);

// sortables options vertical
$sortables_ver          = ($this->params->get("sortableElementsVer", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$sortables_ghost_ver    = $this->params->get("sortableGhostVer", 1);
$sortables_opacity_ver  = $this->params->get("sortableOpacityVer", 0.5);
$sortables_radius_ver   = $this->params->get("sortableRadiusVer", 16);

// sortables options modules
$sortables_modules          = ($this->params->get("sortableElementsModules", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
$sortables_ghost_modules    = $this->params->get("sortableGhostModules", 1);
$sortables_opacity_modules  = $this->params->get("sortableOpacityModules", 0.5);
$sortables_radius_modules   = $this->params->get("sortableRadiusModules", 16);


// moomenu options
$moo_bgiframe           = ($this->params->get("moo_bgiframe'","0") == 0)?"false":"true";
$moo_delay              = $this->params->get("moo_delay", "500");
$moo_duration           = $this->params->get("moo_duration", "600");
$moo_fps                = $this->params->get("moo_fps", "200");
$moo_transition         = $this->params->get("moo_transition", "Sine.easeOut");

$moo_bg_enabled         = ($this->params->get("moo_bg_enabled","1") == 0)?"false":"true";
$moo_bg_over_duration       = $this->params->get("moo_bg_over_duration", "500");
$moo_bg_over_transition     = $this->params->get("moo_bg_over_transition", "Expo.easeOut");
$moo_bg_out_duration        = $this->params->get("moo_bg_out_duration", "600");
$moo_bg_out_transition      = $this->params->get("moo_bg_out_transition", "Sine.easeOut");

$moo_sub_enabled        = ($this->params->get("moo_sub_enabled","1") == 0)?"false":"true";
$moo_sub_opacity        = $this->params->get("moo_sub_opacity","0.95");
$moo_sub_over_duration      = $this->params->get("moo_sub_over_duration", "50");
$moo_sub_over_transition    = $this->params->get("moo_sub_over_transition", "Expo.easeOut");
$moo_sub_out_duration       = $this->params->get("moo_sub_out_duration", "600");
$moo_sub_out_transition     = $this->params->get("moo_sub_out_transition", "Sine.easeIn");
$moo_sub_offsets_top        = $this->params->get("moo_sub_offsets_top", "0");
$moo_sub_offsets_right      = $this->params->get("moo_sub_offsets_right", "1");
$moo_sub_offsets_bottom     = $this->params->get("moo_sub_offsets_bottom", "0");
$moo_sub_offsets_left       = $this->params->get("moo_sub_offsets_left", "1");

require(YOURBASEPATH . "/rt_styleloader.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >

    <head>

        <jdoc:include type="head" />
        <?php
        require(YOURBASEPATH . DS . "rt_utils.php");
        require(YOURBASEPATH . DS . "rt_head_includes.php");
        require(YOURBASEPATH . DS . "rt_sectionrows.php");

        $section_rows = new sectionRows($this);
    ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="verify-v1" content="Z9WJtvhl4rIFVUanvmtEs9VfXjL2jmOz49ns65RZ91Y=" />
<script src="http://bubble.websnapr.com/83m0ddwhbsLq/swh/" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/icon.png" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
<![endif]-->

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Original:  Gilbert Davis -->

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin
function loadImages() {
if (document.getElementById) {  // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
document.getElementById('hidepage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else {
if (document.layers) {  // Netscape 4
document.hidepage.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else {  // IE 4
document.all.hidepage.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
   }
}
//  End -->
</script>
    </head>
    <body OnLoad="loadImages()" id="ff-<?php echo $fontfamily; ?>" class="<?php echo $fontstyle; ?> <?php echo $tstyle; ?> iehandle">
    <div id="hidepage" style="position: absolute; left:5px; top:5px; background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 100%; width: 100%;"> 

<table width=100%><tr><td>Page loading ... Please wait.</td></tr></table></div> 
    <!--Begin Top Bar-->
        <?php if ($show_date == "true" or $show_textsizer == "true" or $this->countModules('top-left or login or top-right')): ?>
        <div id="top-bar">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="top-bar-padding">
                    <div class="topbar-strip">
                        <?php if ($show_date == "true") : ?>
                        <div class="date-block">
                            <span class="date1"><?php $now = &JFactory::getDate(); echo $now->toFormat('%A'); ?></span>,
                            <span class="date2"><?php $now = &JFactory::getDate(); echo $now->toFormat('%B'); ?></span>
                            <span class="date3"><?php $now = &JFactory::getDate(); echo $now->toFormat('%d'); ?></span>,
                            <span class="date4"><?php $now = &JFactory::getDate(); echo $now->toFormat('%Y'); ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($show_textsizer=="true") : ?>
                        <div id="accessibility">
                            <div id="buttons">
                                <a href="<?php echo JROUTE::_($thisurl . "fontstyle=f-larger"); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('INC_FONT_SIZE'); ?>" class="large"><span class="button png">&nbsp;</span></a>
                                <a href="<?php echo JROUTE::_($thisurl . "fontstyle=f-smaller"); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('DEC_FONT_SIZE'); ?>" class="small"><span class="button png">&nbsp;</span></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="textsizer-desc"><?php echo JText::_('TEXT_SIZE'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->countModules('login')) : ?>
                            <?php if ($user->guest) : ?>
                            <a href="#" id="lock-button" rel="rokbox[240 210][module=login-module]"><span id="lock-icon" class="login"></span><span><?php echo JText::_('LOGIN'); ?></span></a>
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <a href="#" id="lock-button" rel="rokbox[240 210][module=login-module]"><span id="lock-icon"></span><span><?php echo JText::_('LOGOUT'); ?></span></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($this->countModules('top-left')) : ?>
                    <div class="topbar-left-mod">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-left" style="xhtml" />
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->countModules('top-right')) : ?>
                    <div class="topbar-right-mod">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-right" style="xhtml" />
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!--End Top Bar-->
        <!--Begin Header-->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-overlay">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <?php if ($this->countModules('logo')) : ?>
                    <div class="logo-module"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" style="xhtml" /></div>
                    <?php elseif ($show_logo == "true") : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>" id="logo" class="png"></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->countModules('search')) : ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="search" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Header-->
        <div id="page-bg"><div id="page-bg2">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <!--Begin Horizontal Menu-->
                <?php if($mtype != "none") : ?>
                <div id="horiz-menu" class="<?php echo $mtype; ?>"><div id="horiz-menu2"><div id="horiz-menu3">
                <?php if($mtype != "module") : ?>
                    <?php echo $topnav; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="toolbar" style="none" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                </div></div></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!--End Horizontal Menu-->
                <div id="vertical-sort">
                <?php

                    echo $section_rows->render();

                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Begin Bottom Section-->
            <div id="bottom-bg">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <?php if ($this->countModules('bottom-menu')) : ?>
                    <div id="bottom-menu"><div id="bottom-menu2"><div id="bottom-menu3"><div id="bottom-menu-overlay">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom-menu" style="xhtml" />
                    </div></div></div></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_topbutton == "true") : ?>
                    <div id="top-button"><a href="#" id="top-scroll" class="top-button-desc"><?php echo JText::_('TOP'); ?></a></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if ($show_copyright == "true" or $this->countModules('footer or bottom or bottom2 or bottom3')) : ?>
            <div id="bottom">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <?php $mClasses = modulesClasses('case7'); if ($this->countModules('bottom or bottom2 or bottom3')) : ?>
                    <div id="bottommodules" class="spacer<?php echo $bottommod_width; ?>">
                        <?php if ($this->countModules('bottom')) : ?>
                        <div class="block <?php echo $mClasses['bottom'][0]; ?>">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom" style="bottom" />
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->countModules('bottom2')) : ?>
                        <div class="block <?php echo $mClasses['bottom2'][0]; ?>">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom2" style="bottom" />
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->countModules('bottom3')) : ?>
                        <div class="block <?php echo $mClasses['bottom3'][0]; ?>">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom3" style="bottom" />
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_copyright == "true") : ?>
                    <div class="copyright-block">
                        <div id="copyright">
                            &copy; <?php echo JText::_('COPYRIGHT'); ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="footer-mod">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml" />
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_defaultsettings == "true") : ?>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-cookies"><?php echo JText::_('DEFAULT_SETTINGS'); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!--End Bottom Section-->
        </div></div>
        <?php if ($this->countModules('debug')) : ?>
        <div id="debug-mod">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" style="none" />
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->countModules('login')) : ?>
        <div id="login-module">
            <?php if ($user->guest) : ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" style="xhtml" />
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="logout">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-2249117-21");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need this "preloader"? What problem do you have without it?

Comment: Some pages take some time to load and it looks like there is no activity, this is just for visitors to not get frustrated :)

Comment: Hmm... well personally I would try to solve the problem of the long page load times, rather than skirting round the issue. Though maybe it's outside your control; I had a similar problem once, caused by an external iframe that was slow.

Comment: I would like that too, but the problem is that it is a Joomla website with a lot of components and a heavy template. It isn't my first choice too, but with this preloader, it looks fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use something existing like this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images-slideshow/9868?

Comment: That's indeed the same outcome, bedankt!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a CSS rule with the following:

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

You should also ensure you have a CSS rule that increases the z-index of your preloader DIV to ensure it sits on top of the rest of the page:

```
#hidepage { z-index: 10000 }
```

Comment: great! , de z-index did the trick, now I only have a last request. Can you also tell me why only 50% of the preloader is white. It looks like only the vissible part of the screen is overlayed and not the complete website.

Comment: @Chris, this is a limitation of your preloader where it cannot obtain the full height of your page, just the screen height.  You could try and use **position: fixed** but you will need to google for cross browser compliance hacks to get this working in IE6 properly.

Comment: Great help, I'll search for a fix, can it be that it takes much longer to load the page with position: fixed?